# Different logging appender on LOG4J

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm using log4j 1.2 and I need to:

- log everything (including logging from referenced libraries) to console
- log from my code to file (and maybe to console)

Using the following code:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CONSOLE
log4j.com.mypackage=ALL, CONSOLE, CSV

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Target=System.err
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n

log4j.appender.CSV=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.CSV.File=./myfile.csv
log4j.appender.CSV.Append=false
log4j.appender.CSV.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CSV.layout.conversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p - %m%n
```

The logfile is not created.

Other try I done:

- If I add CSV appender to rootLogger, then the file is created and filled.
- If I add CSV appender to rootLogger and disable it, then the file is just created.
- If I log only my logger to console... the it works fine

Do you have any idea to solve?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an important part.

The value has to be

```
log4j.logger.com.mypackage
```

Note that you are missing logger in the log definition

Comment: Thanks... but my code works also without "logger". The problem is that it doesn't logs on file, ma only on console.

Comment: Its understandable. Loggers are their to make the debugging easy and it does not play any role in application functionality. If you want the log statement to be in the file, change the property file as mentioned in the post.

Comment: Thanks, but please read again my question, my needs and the try I did... :)

Comment: I know what you have done. Did you try what I have suggested? The change is only for customer logger and not for root logger.

Comment: Yes... I tried your suggestion also. By the way the problem is that it logs on console, but not on file... if I move the file appender on the root logger it works. I'm going to use the log4j.xml approach.